# subclasses with functions having the same name in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have two classes in python, and a third which inherits from the first two:

```
class A():
    def __init__(var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
    def MyFunc():
        #do stuff
class B():
   def __init__(var1):
        self.var1 = var1
    def MyFunc():
        #do other stuff

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3)
        A.__init__(self,var1, var2)
        B.__init__(self, var3)
```

As you might notice both classes have different functions bearing the same name. Doing the following:

```
>>> classC = C(1,2,3)
>>> classC.MyFunc()
```

Appears to work but I would like to be sure of which `MyFunc` function I am calling. How do I control which function from my subclasses is being called?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232098/how-to-call-super-method/31232226

Comment: `super` is often, but not necessarily always, the correct way to handle multiple inheritance.

Comment: In particular, correct use of `super` requires a single class that *doesn't* call `super().MyFunc`, and all other classes implementing `MyFunc` need to subclass (directly or transitively) that class and be sure to use `super().MyFunc` in their own implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attributes not defined by `C` are searched for using `C`'s method resolution order:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Since `C.MyFunc` isn't defined, `classC.MyFunc` resolves to `A.MyFunc`. `B.MyFunc` is never called, unless `A.MyFunc` were to call it explicitly for some reason.

Comment: Ok this partly answers the question, but then how can I control which of the two is called? I have a feeling I'm not setting up class `C` correctly...

Comment: That depends: which do you *want* to be called? If `A.MyFunc`, do nothing; that already happens. If `B.MyFunc` or both, you need to define `C.MyFunc` to make the appropriate calls.

Comment: I want to have control at the level of `C` regarding which function I call, without defining new functions in `C`

Comment: Meaning when I'm inside of C how do I control which function is called

Comment: You explicitly call the one you want, which has to be done from inside `C.MyFunc`. (You could swap the order of `A` and `B` in the parent class list, but that makes *all* methods of one class or another take precedence. If there are any exceptions, you still have to hard-code `C.whatever` to call the non-default one.)