# Redefining a "subclass" sort of structure using inheritance

Tags: python, oop

I am developing an object oriented application which is very similar to the following limited working example. I am initiating 2 super classes. Class `A` and class `B`. Class `A` defines variables `var1` and `var2`, and contains methods `Add`, `Multiply`, `Power`. Class `B` defines variables `var1` and `var2` and contains methods `Subtract`, `Divide` and `Add`.

Class `C` instantiates an instance of both class `A` and class `B`. It then defines a method `f1` which utilizes methods from `A_obj` and `B_obj` with different names. Notice that method `f2` is using the method `Add` from `A_obj` and `B_obj`. The method has the same name but performs a different computation.

The last few lines of the code instantiate an object of class `C` and then prints out the results using both functions.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
    def Add(self):
        result = self.var1 + self.var2
        return result
    def Multiply(self):
        result = self.var1*self.var2
        return result
    def Power(self):
        result = self.var1**self.var2

class B():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
    def Subtract(self):
        result = self.var1-self.var2
        return result
    def Divide(self):
        result = self.var1/self.var2
        return result
    def Add(self):
        result = self.var1+self.var2+self.var1+self.var2
        return result
class C():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4):
        self.A_obj = A(var1,var2)
        self.B_obj = B(var3,var4)
    def f1(self):
        result = self.A_obj.Add()+self.B_obj.Subtract()
        return result
    def f2(self):
        result = self.A_obj.Add()-self.B_obj.Add()
        return result
C_obj = C(1, 2, 3,4)

print(C_obj.f1())
print(C_obj.f2())
```

My question is, can I achieve this sort of functionality using **inheritance**? Is **inheritance** even an appropriate concept to use here? I tried forcing it in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324737/calling-similar-named-functions-in-subclasses-from-superclass) but found out that as soon as you use inheritance variables in subclass `C` become "globally defined" and are recognized by superclasses `A` and `B`. I'd like to make sure everything in class `A` remains local to `A` and everything in class `B` remain local to `B`.

Comment: yes I will correct now. Sorry about that.

Comment: You *have* inheritance here already - although you also seem to be using composition for some reason. I am completely unable to understand your question or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As you've already said, if `C` inherits from `A` and `B` then you'll only have one set of `var1` and `var2` attributes, not two. So no, you can't use inheritance unless you rename `var1` and `var2` in either `A` or `B`.

Comment: I thought inheritance occurs when you supply superclasses in the arguments of the class definition.  For instance `C(A,B)`. That is true inheritance. What I'm doing above seems like a not very elegant way to solve the problem. Also could use name mangling but that does not remove the "global" vs "local" problem

Comment: @Daniel Roseman. Yes I agree that I am using composition. I dont think I'm using inheritance in this particular question. Where do you see  it?

Comment: Ah I see, the definition for class C was `C(A,B)`. Thats not really necessary for this script. I reduced it to `C()`