# How to call grandparent's `__str__` from child class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose we have 3 classes `grandparent`,`parent` and `child` where `parent` inherits from `grandparent` and `child` inherits from `parent`. I want to call the `__str__` of `grandparent` in class `child`. How can I do it?

```
class grandparent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return f'grandparent'

class parent(grandparent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{super().__str__()},parent'

    
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{super().__str__()},child'
```

In this case if I make an object from `child` class, after printing it I see :

```
c = child()
print(c) # prints 'grandparent,parent,child'
```

I want to see  `'grandparent,child'` by calling the grandparent's `__str__` in child class.

Comment: You really shouldn't. If you find yourself needing to do this, you should rethink your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: If you don't want the parent involved in the chain, just delete `parent.__str__`.

Comment: Inheritance graphs can be tricky. Do you want the "grandparent" from Method Resolution Ordier (MRO) or exactly the `grandparent` class?

Comment: It seems like what you are **really** trying to do is get every child in the hierarchy to reuse and modify the `grandparent`'s logic directly. Consider using a template-and-hook strategy instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call super method from grandchild class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232098/how-to-call-super-method-from-grandchild-class)

Comment: @user2357112 no, I was just curious about it. I wanted to understand its hierarchy better.

Comment: @tdelaney I wanted it from Method resolution order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways how to achieve this.

First is to pass `parent` class to `super` method:

```
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{super(parent, self).__str__()},child'
```

In that case we don't need to know "*grandparent*" class name. In case if you know the name of "*grantparent*" class we could use direct class name:

```
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{grandparent.__str__(self)},child'
```

Those 2 methods is the best practice, any of other approaches does not so flexible.

Comment: i forgot you could pass parent to super! this is probably the most right answer imho

Comment: I don't see the logic here. If you want to ignore MRO when looking a super classes, go all the way: `return grandparent.__str__(self)`

Answer (score 4):

You can always call the method directly:

```py
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{grandparent.__str__(self)},child'
```

Output as requested.

Comment: this is probably better than my crappy mro hack :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Don't worry, I'm mightily impressed ;-)

Comment: @JoranBeasley - it all depends on how OP defines "grandparent". Yours is great if you want an MRO respecting grandparent.

Answer (score 1):

its pretty hacky but

```
>>> class child(parent):
...     def __str__(self):
...          return self.__class__.mro()[-2].__str__(self) + ":child"
```

this uses `mro` (method resolution order) to get the 2nd to last parent class (the last is always object)

if you wanted to get the current class that is

```
def class_mro(self)
      current_class = self.__class__.mro()[0]
      parent_class = self.__class__.mro()[1]
      grandparent_class = self.__class__.mro()[2]
      ...
      non_object_root_class=self.__class__.mro()[-2]
      object_class = self.__class__.mro()[-1]


print(child.mro())
[<class '__main__.child'>, <class '__main__.parent'>, <class '__main__.grandparent'>, <class 'object'>]
```

but this will breakdown if you are using multiple inheritance

```
class B:
    pass
class child(parent,B):
    pass
print(child.mro())
[<class '__main__.child'>, <class '__main__.parent'>, <class '__main__.grandparent'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer given OP's comment _I wanted it from Method resolution order_. Except wouldn't it be `return self.__class__.mro()[2].__str__(self) + ":child"`? `-2` counts forward from `object` instead of backwards from `child`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the **str** method of child class to return your expected result.

```
    def __str__(self):
      return f'{grandparent.__str__(self)}, child'
```

If you call:

```
c = child()
print(c)
```

then it will print: grandparent, child